# switch between views of 2 xib

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

i hv to xib

first xib contains 4 views, and second xib contains only one view.

v1,v2,v3,v4
i need to navigate from 2nd xib's view to first xib's 2nd view (i.e v2)_..

how can i do that
regards
shishir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the 2nd xib is associated with its own view controller then call up that view controller in any of the usual ways - push it onto the stack, display it as a modal view etc.